# how to recognized the next string after the string that you have specified in Java

Tags: substring

Hello I am just learning to use Java...

Can someone please help me how I can extract a word from a user input?

For example, I want my program to ask what is her favorite color and favorite food?

so if the user input

Color: blue food: chicken

I want to recognize the blue and the chicken using substring...

So my question comes down to how I can use the substring so that it recognize only one token after "Color: " or after "food: "

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how *you* tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us *exactly* what the result was and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you really need to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully working code. Feel free to use this in your IDE to get a feel on how input is taken in, and how you can manipulate it in different ways. Happy Learnings!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

     String first_name;
     System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
     first_name = user_input.next();

     String last_name;
     System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
     last_name = user_input.next();String full_name;

     full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
     System.out.println("You are " + full_name);
    }
   }
```